# Find lambda for exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

I'm trying to find the function which allows me to find lambda if:

$$y = 1-e^{-\lambda x}\,.$$

I tried doing this by:

\begin{eqnarray} 
y-1 &=& -e^{-\lambda x}\\
e^{-\lambda x} &=& -(y-1)\\
-\lambda x &=& \ln(-(y-1))\\
-\lambda &=& (\ln(-(y-1))) / x\\
\lambda &=& -(\ln(-(y-1))) / x
\end{eqnarray}

But to my knowledge this doesn't work if $y-1$ is positive.
Have I done this algebra correctly?

Comment: If $y - 1 > 0$, then $y> 1.$ $1 - e^{-\Lambda}$ can never be larger than one.

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be working with a cdf, keep in mind that $y$ -- being a probability -- must lie between 0 and 1, and being a continuous variate, it has 0 probability of taking any specific value. (You don't need it to be a cdf, specifically, you can verify that $y$ never exceeds 1 in any case, but it's important to keep properties of cdfs in mind if you're using them.)

Your basic approach is okay, though it could be written in a simpler way than you have it.

Comment: If you had the time I'd appreciate an example of simpler writing? (bad with algebra but desperately trying to learn).

Comment: An example would be $1-y$ instead of $-(y-1)$; it's more concise. It's fine to leave it as $-(y-1)$ for a few steps if you think it's going to simplify (e.g. by the availability of another minus sign in a few steps) or if you particularly need to keep a (y-1) term visible.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to define your symbols and put in the domain for the various quantities.  It would be worth reading the [MathJax tutorial & quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can make your mathematics look how you want it.

Comment: I have made a few edits to your question. Please check it looks like the way you want it to.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the suggestions! Highly helpful.